# Create an iam role under specific aws account using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm really new to terraform and has been stuck in this for a while.

So I'm using an external module which creates an aws_iam_role and also corresponding policies. In my terraform code, I just use the following code to create the module but how can I make sure the roles are created under specific aws account? I have multiple aws accounts right now but I just want the external module to be in one of them. The account id for the target aws account is known. Thanks!

```
module "<external_module>" {
  source                 = "git::..."
  ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without more context it's a bit hard to understand what you want. Usually, by defining a named profile to use in the provider configuration is enough. Did you define the `provider` block, how are you using AWS credentials (i.e., a file, named profile, IAM role...)?

Comment: You have to provide AWS credentials to Terraform. Those credentials are going to be for one specific AWS account, and that is the account Terraform will create resources in. If your use case is more complicated than that, then you need to provide more details in your question.